# Selendroid SetupError

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selendroid

Am getting below error while setup.
I have setup my `ANDRIOD_HOME` variable too. But still getting the below error.
Can anyone help me on this:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException:` Enviro
nment variable '`ANDROID_HOME`' was not found!

Answer (score 0):

Please setup Android sdk correctly. If you don't know how to do it, have a look at this guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/issues/198

I got these issues resolved.

Do vote the answer after you get your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_HOME variable should point to the SDK:

> **set ANDROID_HOME=C:\${installation location}\SDK
>
>   set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools**
>   [Try setting path through the command prompt before running selendroid]

(This is only for Windows. For other OS you can check this link:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)